# RecordId or any Other Unique id for a Excel File

Tags: c#, ms-office, office-interop

I am developing an Application using vc++ and C# ,the application can Import and Export data to Excel file.
 I am using Interop assemblies provided by microsoft. My Problem user imports data from excel and he modifies the data and when he is transfer back to excel ,then istead of creating a new row. My application should update the existing row which has the same data .

For example
   I have an excel file which has 10 Colums and 100 rows . I am importing this to my application and I updating the data in 10th row . and I am exporting this back to the same excel file.  My requirement is this should update the 10th row in my excel file.

My Doubt is in excel whether we have any record id which is unique to each row and this Id should not be created by user . I am using C# for Communicating with Excel. Is there any sample codes for it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then, when reading the data from the excel file, you would have to store the sheet name and row/column index.

There is no unique ID of a cell, just the cell name or the indices.